# how to sort by timestamp field while counting duplicates

Tags: mysql, count, sorting

I have a table with username, timestamp and action columns. I need to retrieve a list of usernames, total occurrences of each user and the latest timestamp for each user. The following statement works but it doesn't sort the timestamp field. I've tried adding "ORDER BY time DESC" but it has no effect. How can I retrieve the latest timestamp? The statement below returns the first occurrence of the timestamp.

```
user|time|action
jones|1-1-2016|actionA
jones|1-2-2016|actionA
jones|2-1-2016|actionB

SELECT user, time, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user 
HAVING total > 0
```

Expected Results:

```
jones|2-1-2016|3
```

Comment: The `HAVING total > 0` is useless. `COUNT(*)` can never be 0 in a simple query like this (only in a correlated subquery it could)

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply a `MAX`:

```
SELECT user, MAX(time), COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC
```

Of course, this assumes that `time` is actually a `datetime` or `timestamp`and not a `VarChar`.

Comment: And be sure to use the `DATE` datatype, not `VARCHAR`, for `time`.

Comment: @RickJames: As the OP talked about a *timestamp field* I assumed he's using a correct datatype :)